# Using TikZ to label a Commutative Diagram with a Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a beamer presentation and having some diagram troubles. Is it possible to label an arrow in `tikzcd` with a `tikzpicture`?

For example, the code

```
\begin{tikzcd}
S^1
\arrow{r}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1 and 2);
\draw[thick] (0,2) arc (450:270:2 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\pgfmatrixnextcell
\varnothing
\end{tikzcd}
```

produces

[image]

which is obviously deficient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first save the `tikzpicture` in a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1 and 2);
\draw[thick] (0,2) arc (450:270:2 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
S^1
\arrow{r}{\usebox\mybox}
\pgfmatrixnextcell
\varnothing
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]